# SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault with memcpy_avx_unaligned

Tags: segmentation-fault, gdb, memcpy

I am trying to copy 4 bytes form **s** to **handler->data** didn't understand the error.

Tried to debug with gdb, but everything looks good.

```
memcpy(handler->data + handler->len, s->begin, num_bytes);   
(gdb) p handler->data   
$5 = (uint8_t *) 0x0   
(gdb) p s->begin   
$6 = (const uint8_t *) 0x7ffcfda705b2 "D"   
(gdb) s  
__memcpy_avx_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-avx-unaligned.S:41 41     
../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/memcpy-avx-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the issue.
I failed to initialize this **handler->data**.

Comment: And that is _obvious_ from the `p handler->data` in your GDB output (copying to `NULL` pointer isn't going to end well).

Comment: Right, I have a weak understanding of pointers, so didn't think initially that was an issue.